# É possivel executar o Acrobat Reader sem colocar todo o caminho do seu executável?

Tags: java, pdf

Estou abrindo arquivos no formato PDF pelo Java e para isso estou executando o Acrobat pelo Java também, segue linha do caminho para o executável do Acrobat:

```
String cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe";
```

Porém algumas vezes pode ser que o executável do Acrobat não esteja neste caminho, a questão é possível executar o Acrobat pelo sem ter que indicar todo o seu caminho no Java?

O código completo é esse:

```
String cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe";

String param1 = "/A";
String param2 = "page=" + Integer.toString(i) + "&zoom=150";

String[] cmds = new String[]{cmd, param1, param2, pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()};
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmds).start();
```

Comment: Desculpe, postei uma resposta mas acabei não perguntando se você pretende só abrir o acrobat ou desejaria abrir um arquivo qualquer em pdf.

Comment: É que como preciso abrir determinadas paginas eu preciso passar parâmetros como página é o caminho

Comment: Mas qual é o problema do caminho?! Geralmente quando se instala Acrobat Reader sempre o caminho é o mesmo. A não ser que seja windows 32 ou 64bits. Ai você pode fazer uma condição verificando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Porém algumas vezes pode ser que o executável do Acrobat não esteja neste caminho, a questão é possível executar o Acrobat pelo sem ter que indicar todo o seu caminho no Java?

O arquivo terá que ser aberto exclusivamente com o Acrobat? caso não for, você poderá abrir o arquivo com o programa associado para aquele tipo de arquivo com o método [`Desktop#open`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)):

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
   try {
       File myFile = new File("c:\\teste1.pdf");
       Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       // Não há programas instalados para abrir esse arquivo
   }
}
```

Se for necessário passar argumentos para o arquivo, o método `Desktop#open` pode não servir neste caso.

O que você terá que fazer é procurar o tipo de arquivo da extensão com o comando [`assoc`](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/323526) e usar o comando [`ftype`](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) para obter o programa associado ao tipo de arquivo.

[**Nessa resposta do SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30166136/1608936) mostra como implementar isso:

```
public static void openPdfWithParams(File pdfFile, String params){  
    try {
        // encontra o tipo de arquivo da extensão pdf
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c assoc .pdf");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String type = line.substring(line.indexOf("=")+1);
        reader.close();

        // encontra o executável associado ao tipo de arquivo
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ftype " + type);
        p.waitFor();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        line = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
        String exec = line.substring(line.indexOf("=") + 1);

        // Substitui "%1" parâmetros e o caminho de arquivo
        String commandParams = String.format("/A \"%s\" \"%s\"", params ,pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
        String command = exec.replace("\"%1\"", commandParams);
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao tentar abrir o arquivo PDF");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Para usar, faça assim:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    openPdfWithParams(new File("C:\\teste1.pdf"), "page=5&zoom=150");
}
```

A linha acima vai tentar abrir o arquivo *C:\teste1.pdf* na página *5* com *zoom* de *150* com o programa associado para abrir arquivos `.pdf`.

Comment: Pois é, é que se coloco desse jeito ele está danado erro.

Comment: Eu fiz dessa forma e continua a abrir o pdf na página 01 sempre

Comment: @R.Santos Editei a resposta, testei aqui e funcionou, veja se funciona para você.

Comment: Perfeito @zekk, era isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Teria uma outra alternativa de abrir um arquivo `.pdf`, porem assim:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // o arquivo myfile.pdf sera aberto assim
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "c:\\myfile.pdf");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + e); //imprime o erro
    }
}
```

Comment: Sabe dizer se tem como possar argumentos ao comando via `getRuntime().exec`?