# Como abrir txt em java para usuario

Tags: java

Crio um txt e consigo ler também
porém como faço para abrir ele pro usuário como se tivesse clicado nele? pode ser pelo bloco de notas mesmo ou fazer com que ele selecione o programa...

Comment: Recomendo leitura: [ask]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É possivel executar o Acrobat Reader sem colocar todo o caminho do seu executável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148076/%c3%89-possivel-executar-o-acrobat-reader-sem-colocar-todo-o-caminho-do-seu-execut%c3%a1ve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma solução...

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad C:\\arq.txt");
```